# Azure CosmosDB COUNT Consuming a lot of RU/s (MongoDB)

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection with ~8000 documents that I paginate in my application. However, my query to get the count of total documents (to calculate page count), is blowing my RU/s quota out of the water.

The find query only takes about 3 RU/s, but takes a while to execute...

Is there a solution to this?

```
db.orders.count({"user": ObjectId("5ca51dc1234c0b21dcxxa12c")}})
Operation consumed 442.62 RUs
5958
```

Comment: what's your `count` query actually executing?

Comment: @MarkC. I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. The query is above.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't sure if this was a method you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

It will search all the partitions in your container, Pass the partition Key with your query inorder to make the search easier, otherwise it has to go through all the parititions in the container, that will result in lot of RUs.

Answer (score 0):

If the find query takes a lot of time, then make sure that you have an index on this field. Currently they seem to be added automatically for each field, so it shouldn't be an issue.

However, from my own recent experience with Cosmos DB, if count returns a large number, it will also consume a lot of RUs. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60512604/4619705 for more info.